# How to highlight some words in Eshell?

Tags: emacs, eshell

I use Eshell in Emacs to run a program and I could check the output in the Shell , but I want to highlight some words like ‘errors’ ‘info’,or other words like that. How could I do that ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun font-lock-comment-annotations ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("\\<\\(error\\)" 1 font-lock-warning-face t)
     ("\\<\\(info\\)" 1 'org-todo t)
   ))
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'font-lock-comment-annotations)
```

Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [nschum/highlight-symbol.el](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el), like this:

[image: highlight]